# QuerySelector of javascript VS Find() of Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

On performance basics **QuerySelector()** of javascript or **Find()** of Jquery which is better to use in code on factors like **speed** and **efficent access to Dom Elements**

```
element = document.querySelector(selectors);
```

or

```
element= $(document).find(selectors);
```

Comment: You should learn the reasoning behind / history of jquery.  It was never meant to be the fastest, it was meant to unify the **chaotic mess** that was caused by the first browser wars.  It still provides a succinct development terminology (compared with the excessive verbosity of native javascript), but browsers have come a long way and browser developers have recognised the need for standards compliance, reducing the *need* for jquery on the browser, but not reducing the need for jquery's rapid development and continued power that it provides.

Comment: Ya what you said is perfect, Thanks for the details @freedomn-m

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`querySelector` is far more performant. It doesn't require a library nor the construction of a jQuery object.

Warning, the following will *block* your browser for a little bit, depending on your computer's specs:

```js
const t0 = performance.now();
for (let i = 0; i < 1e6; i++) {
  const div = document.querySelector('div');
}
const t1 = performance.now();
for (let i = 0; i < 1e6; i++) {
  const div = $(document).find('div');
}
const t2 = performance.now();

console.log('querySelector: ' + (t1 - t0));
console.log('jQuery: ' + (t2 - t1));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>some div</div>
```

That said, performance for selecting a single element will rarely matter - I think it would only be something to consider if it's done in a nested loop, for example, and is done thousands of times in under a second.